# Initialize a Guid variable which will be assigned later

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, guid

I have to write event receivers for SharePoint lists (SharePoint 2013). For logging purposes, I am declaring my Guid variable (corresponding to a Project) globally and then assigning a value to it whenever required in the event receivers (Item Adding, Item Updating, etc...).

Below is the code sample:

```
public class ClassName : SPItemEventReceiver
{
    Guid prjguid;
    public override void ItemAdding(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {
        base.ItemAdding(properties);
        try
        {
            prjguid = new Guid(properties.Site.OpenWeb().AllProperties["MSPWAPROJUID"].ToString());
            .
            .
            .
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Exception Handling
            WriteLog(prjguid + ex.message);
        }
    }
    public void WriteLog(string message)
    {
        // Logging
    }
}
```

This code throws en exception:
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Any possible explanations where I am going wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you do not mention where this exception is thrown there are several possible reasons for this exception:

Possible reason 1:

If an exception is happening within your `properties.Site.OpenWeb().AllProperties["MSPWAPROJUID"].ToString()`
call the *prjguid* variable will not get assigned.

Then in your catch WriteLog method you want to print out this *prjguid * variable.

This is where your variable can be null.

Inside your catch you could try to change your code to

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
        // Exception Handling
     if(prjguid != null)
     {
        WriteLog(prjguid + ex.message);
     }else
     {
        WriteLog(ex.message);
     }
}
```

Possible reason 2:

properties.Site.OpenWeb() returns null

Possible reason 3:

properties.Site.OpenWeb().AllProperties["MSPWAPROJUID"] returns null

For case 2 and 3 you have to seperate those calls an check for null for both parts.